# Move big zero in Matrix for better alignment

Tags: align, matrices

I wanted to know if it is possible to move the zeros in the Matrix to the new positions in red like this?:

[image]

Does this appear more presentable?

Here is my code so far:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage{blkarray}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb,amsthm, bm}
\newcommand\bigzero{\makebox(0,0){\text{\huge0}}}

\begin{document}

\[
\begin{blockarray}{cccccc}
       &[1-5]      &[5-10]& [11-15]& \cdots & [195-200]  \\
\begin{block}{c(ccccc)}
1      &  1        &      &        &        &            \\
2      &           &  1   &        &        &\bigzero    \\
3      &           &      &  1     &        &            \\
\vdots &  \bigzero &      &        & \ddots &            \\
40     &           &      &        &        &  1         \\
\end{block}
\end{blockarray}
 \]

\end{document}
```

If I move the `\bigzero` around in the current alignment, like this:

[image]

I still think that the appearance in not "that presentable".  Is there a way to manually adjust exactly where you want the zeros placed?

Thanks!

Comment: Exactly what do you want to do? The first zero can be shifted just by moving `\bigzero` one column to the left; the second zero can be shifted to the right if you move it one column to the right; but it looks like you also want to shift it up vertically. Can you comment on why the "column-shifted" versions are not good enough for what you want to do?

Comment: In other words, can you specify where and how exactly you want the big zeroes to align?

Comment: @WillieWong, Hello, please see my updated edits.  I wanted the `\bigzero` to appear where the red zeros are in the original image.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `\raisebox` to adjust the height of the zeros. Your example

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage{blkarray}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb,amsthm, bm}
\newcommand\bigzero{\makebox(0,0){\text{\huge0}}}
\begin{document}

\[
\begin{blockarray}{cccccc}
       &[1-5]      &[5-10]& [11-15]& \cdots & [195-200]  \\
\begin{block}{c(ccccc)}
1      &  1        &      &        &        &            \\
2      &           &  1   &        & \bigzero &    \\
3      &           &  \raisebox{-2ex}[0ex][0ex]{\bigzero} &  1     &        &            \\
\vdots &           &      &        & \ddots &            \\
40     &           &      &        &        &  1         \\
\end{block}
\end{blockarray}
 \]

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

The top-right one one column to the left with a `\quad` spacing, and the bottom-left one a column to the right and lifted up with `\multirow` looks much like your example, I think.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage{blkarray}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb,amsthm, bm}
\newcommand\bigzero{\makebox(0,0){\text{\huge0}}}
\usepackage{multirow}
\begin{document}

\[
\begin{blockarray}{cccccc}
       &[1-5]      &[5-10]& [11-15]& \cdots & [195-200]  \\
\begin{block}{c(ccccc)}
1      &  1        &      &        &        &            \\
2      &           &  1   &        &   \quad\bigzero      &   \\
3      &           &     &  1     &        &            \\
\vdots &  &   \multirow{-2}*{\bigzero}   &        & \ddots &            \\
40     &           &      &        &        &  1         \\
\end{block}
\end{blockarray}
 \]

\end{document}
```